# Pdf Reader on Ubuntu 20.04 which has capability of choosing text and bacground color

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I used to read a lot of pdf books. So I used adobe reader on windows with gray background and black text color which I feel comforting for the eyes. I have tried different pdf readers which have corol inversion option and it is not modifiable. Is there any pdf reader with customizable
text and background color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okular.

Reasons:

- Multiple platforms (Windows, MacOS, Linux, mobile)
- Clean and easy-to-use interface
- Annotation tools
- Supports multiple formats (PDF, ePub, DjVu, CHM, Postscript, DVI, TIFF, ODF, XPS, etc.)
- Open Source

Comment: I tried okular and it doesn't solve my problem of customizable background and text color problem.

Comment: Have you tried: Settings > Configure Okular > Accessibility > Change Color?

Comment: Oh thanks. I did not dig into the options. It worked as I wanted, although a dark interface would be very helpful.

Comment: Okular follows your global system theme. So, if you have a dark theme installed then it should follow that theme. You can also change the background color by doing: Settings > Configure Okular > Use custom background color.

Comment: In the appearance settings I have dark mode selected and all other apps use dark interface but okular remains the same. As you said, I also tried Use custom background color and changed it to black but the interface remains white.

Comment: Are you using the Snap version of Okular? You can check using the command `snap list | grep okular`. I could be wrong but I think that Snaps don't play nicely with the system theme. If you are then I would suggest uninstalling it with `sudo snap remove okular` and installing it using Apt like so `sudo apt-get install okular`